# Как добавлять svg иконки из админки wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

пытаюсь(учусь) посадить верстку на WP, рядом с заголовком новости вставляется иконка svg(все иконки svg находятся в спрайте и вызываются через id), не могу найти инфу как сделать чтобы эти иконки добавлять из админки WP, а то что сделал я, она у меня просто дублируется при создании нового поста

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <!-- post -->
            <div class="info_block">
                <div class="info_title_w">
                    <svg class="style-svg icon icon-gear color">
                        <use xlink:href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/i/sprite/sprite.svg#gear"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <h2 class="info_title title_main"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="info_text">
                    <?php the_excerpt();?>
                </div>
                <a class="info_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">more</a>
                <div class="info_tags"><?php the_tags('<span>Теги:</span> ');?></div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- post navigation -->
            <?php else: ?>
            <!-- no posts found -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

сделал кое какие правки, не знаю это костыльно или нет, вроде работает, проделал следующее, установил плагин support svg, в раздел Медиафайлы добавил свг файлы, затем зашел в нужную запись и там "Добавить изображение записи", далее изменил код на следующий: 
1) в фале index.php

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <!-- post -->
            <div class="info_block">
                <div class="info_title_w">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', $svg_attr ); ?> <!-- Заменил инлайновый свг на этот код -->
                    <h2 class="info_title title_main"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="info_text">
                    <?php the_excerpt();?>
                </div>
                <a class="info_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">more</a>
                <div class="info_tags"><?php the_tags('<span>Теги:</span> ');?></div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- post navigation -->
            <?php else: ?>
            <!-- no posts found -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

2) в файле functions.php дописал

```
// описание функции для the_post_thumbnail
$svg_attr = array(
  'class' => "style-svg icon-size color",
);
```

вот только если в этот пост нужно будет вставить еще и изображение, то я тогда не знаю как это сделать, еще один код `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` просто дублирует свг, как можно это без костылей сделать чтобы можно было еще пару картинок влепить ?